# How to run Android Things App Inventor Companion on RasPi 3b?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, app-inventor, android-things

I am building an Android Things device which should run an app built in MIT App Inventor. The app must use 4 GPIO pins for output. To accomplish this, my plan is to use an Android Things GPIO [extension](https://github.com/thilankam/androidthings-appinventor-companion) built by Thilanka Munasinghe. His tutorial is [here](http://thilankam.github.io/mit-app-inventor/#/androidthings/gpioinput).

My problem is the ambiguity in the step labeled "Run the Android Things App Inventor Companion on your board". I don't understand how it wants me to load this software onto the board. I think it means us to load it from Android Studio, but nothing shows up when I open the project with AS. (I have very limited experience with AS, so this could be a misunderstanding on my part). Upon running this software on the board, there's supposed to be output in the "console" (the mention of a console is what makes me think this is supposed to be run from AS) that provides information to correctly talk to the GPIO pins from the MIT App. I can then use that information in the blocks in the MIT App Inventor to send signals out from the GPIO when certain conditions are met.

If anyone can provide some guidance, that would be greatly appreciated. I've scoured the Internet for days looking for a solution, but have had no luck. I'm using the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, and Android Things version 1.0.14, although I can roll back to and older version of Android Things if necessary.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Quick look at the github page of the project, it looks like an Android Studio project, you should be able to open the folder `Companion` and see a project, then you have to compile it and install the apk on the Android Things board.

Detailed instructions on how to connect to an Android Things board (depending if it is a Raspberry Pi or an iMX7D) can be found on the official docs: https://developer.android.com/things/get-started/kits